# PyQt получение вводимых значений из QLineEdit

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt5, pyqt, qlineedit

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from ui import Ui_Form
from pickle import TRUE
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import os

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)


# Создание формы
Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
ui = Ui_Form()
ui.setupUi(Form)
Form.show()


HEADERS = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36',
    'accept' : '*/*'
}

URL = 'https://www.sulpak.kz/f/smartfoniy'

FILE = 'grgr.csv'


def btn():
    parse()

ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(btn)


def get_html(url, params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r

def get_pages_count(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    pagination = soup.select('div.pages-list a')
    if pagination:
        return int(pagination[-1].get_text().replace('\n', ''))
    else:
        return 1

def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all("li", class_="tile-container")
    
    phones = []
    for item in items:
        old_price = item.find('div', class_='old-price')
        price = item.find('span', class_='hidden', text='Цена:')
        if old_price:
            old_price = old_price.get_text().replace('₸', '')
        else:
            old_price = 'Скидки нет'
        if price:
            price = price.find_next('span').get_text().replace('₸', '')
        else:
            price = 'Нет в наличии'
        phones.append({
            'title': item.find('h3', class_='title').get_text(strip=TRUE).replace('\n', ''),
            'price': price,
            'old price' : old_price,
        })    
    return phones


def save_file(items, path):
    with open(path, 'w', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
        writer.writerow(['Модель', 'Цена', 'Цена без скидки'])
        for item in items:
            writer.writerow([item['title'], item['price'], item['old price']])

            
def parse():
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        phones = []
        pages_count = get_pages_count(html.text)
        for page in range(1, pages_count + 1):
            print(f'Парсинг страницы {page} из {pages_count}...')
            html = get_html(URL, params={'page': page})
            phones.extend(get_content(html.text))
        save_file(phones, FILE)
        print(f'Получено {len(phones)} товаров')
        os.startfile(FILE)
    else: 
        print('Error')


sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**ui.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(700, 700)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(1)
        Form.setFont(font)
        Form.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        Form.setStyleSheet("background: rgb(112, 112, 112);")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 400, 300, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(1)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("    QPushButton{\n"
"\n"
"background: rgb(61,181,233);\n"
"    height: 50px;\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"    text-align: center;\n"
"    font-size: 20px;\n"
"    font-weight: bold;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"background: rgb(52, 148, 189)\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 320, 340, 50))
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("    QLineEdit{\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"    font-size: 20px;\n"
"    font-weight: bold;\n"
"    background: white;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"    QLineEdit:hover {\n"
"    border: 3px solid rgb(61,181,233);\n"
"    }")
        self.lineEdit.setInputMask("")
        self.lineEdit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 240, 340, 50))
        self.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet("    QLineEdit{\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"    font-size: 20px;\n"
"    font-weight: bold;\n"
"    background: white;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"    QLineEdit:hover {\n"
"    border: 3px solid rgb(61,181,233);\n"
"    }")
        self.lineEdit_2.setInputMask("")
        self.lineEdit_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(Form)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(175, 130, 350, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(1)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.comboBox.setFont(font)
        self.comboBox.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.comboBox.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.comboBox.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.comboBox.setStyleSheet("QComboBox{\n"
"    border-radius: 30px;\n"
"    padding-left: 140px;\n"
"    background:rgb(56, 56, 56);\n"
"    border-bottom: 5px solid rgb(89, 133, 255);\n"
"    font-size: 20px;\n"
"    color: #fff;\n"
"    font-weight: bold;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QComboBox QAbstractItemView {\n"
"    text-align: center;\n"
"    border-radius: 20px;\n"
"    background-color:rgb(56, 56, 56);\n"
"    color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QComboBox::drop-down {\n"
"    width: 25px;\n"
"    height: 25px;\n"
"    top: 15px;\n"
"    right: 15px;\n"
"}")
        self.comboBox.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhNone)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 499, 400, 151))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(1)
        self.widget.setFont(font)
        self.widget.setStyleSheet("background: #fff;\n"
"color: black;")
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Начать"))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("Form", "Введите URL каталога"))
        self.lineEdit_2.setPlaceholderText(_translate("Form", "Введите название файла"))
        self.comboBox.setCurrentText(_translate("Form", "Sulpak"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("Form", "Sulpak"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("Form", "Мечта"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Имеется код такой, как я могу в переменные `URL` и `FILE` присвоить значения из `QLineEdit`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Данил, вы забыли опубликовать модуль `ui.py`

Comment: @S.Nick Добавил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[text : QString](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#text-prop)

Это свойство содержит текст редактирования строки.

Например так:  `self.url = self.lineEdit.text()`

---

Ваша задача тяжелая и должна выполняться в дополнительном потоке, примерно так:

```
import sys
import os
import csv
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


from pickle import TRUE
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


#from ui import Ui_Form
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(700, 700)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(1)
        Form.setFont(font)
        Form.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        Form.setStyleSheet("background: rgb(112, 112, 112);")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 400, 300, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(1)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("    QPushButton{\n"
"\n"
"background: rgb(61,181,233);\n"
"    height: 50px;\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"    text-align: center;\n"
"    font-size: 20px;\n"
"    font-weight: bold;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"background: rgb(52, 148, 189)\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 320, 340, 50))
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("    QLineEdit{\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"    font-size: 20px;\n"
"    font-weight: bold;\n"
"    background: white;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"    QLineEdit:hover {\n"
"    border: 3px solid rgb(61,181,233);\n"
"    }")
        self.lineEdit.setInputMask("")
        self.lineEdit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 240, 340, 50))
        self.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet("    QLineEdit{\n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"    font-size: 20px;\n"
"    font-weight: bold;\n"
"    background: white;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"    QLineEdit:hover {\n"
"    border: 3px solid rgb(61,181,233);\n"
"    }")
        self.lineEdit_2.setInputMask("")
        self.lineEdit_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(Form)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(175, 130, 350, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(1)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.comboBox.setFont(font)
        self.comboBox.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.comboBox.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.comboBox.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.comboBox.setStyleSheet("QComboBox{\n"
"    border-radius: 30px;\n"
"    padding-left: 140px;\n"
"    background:rgb(56, 56, 56);\n"
"    border-bottom: 5px solid rgb(89, 133, 255);\n"
"    font-size: 20px;\n"
"    color: #fff;\n"
"    font-weight: bold;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QComboBox QAbstractItemView {\n"
"    text-align: center;\n"
"    border-radius: 20px;\n"
"    background-color:rgb(56, 56, 56);\n"
"    color: white;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QComboBox::drop-down {\n"
"    width: 25px;\n"
"    height: 25px;\n"
"    top: 15px;\n"
"    right: 15px;\n"
"}")
        self.comboBox.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhNone)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")

# +++                  
#        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Form)
# +++                           ^^^^^^^^^   
 
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 499, 400, 151))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)                                            # +++ 12
        self.widget.setFont(font)
        self.widget.setStyleSheet("background: #fff;\n"
"color: black;")
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Начать"))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("Form", "Введите URL каталога"))
        self.lineEdit_2.setPlaceholderText(_translate("Form", "Введите название файла"))
        self.comboBox.setCurrentText(_translate("Form", "Sulpak"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("Form", "Sulpak"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("Form", "Мечта"))


class Thread(QThread):
    stepChanged = pyqtSignal(int, int)
    finished = pyqtSignal(list)
    error = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, url, file, HEADERS):
        super().__init__()
        self.url = url
        self.file = file
        self.HEADERS = HEADERS


    def run(self):        
        self.parse()   
        
    def parse(self):
    
#        html = get_html(URL)
        html = self.get_html()
        if not html:
            if html != False:
                self.error.emit(
                    f'Error: status_code={html.status_code}'
                )
            return
        
        if html.status_code == 200:
            phones = []
            pages_count = self.get_pages_count(html.text)
            for page in range(1, pages_count + 1):
#                print(f'Парсинг страницы {page} из {pages_count}...')
                self.stepChanged.emit(page, pages_count)
                
                html = self.get_html(params={'page': page})
                phones.extend(self.get_content(html.text))
                self.msleep(50)
                
            self.finished.emit(phones)
            '''            
            save_file(phones, FILE)
            print(f'Получено {len(phones)} товаров')
            os.startfile(FILE)
            '''
            
        else: 
#            print('Error')
            self.error.emit(f'Error: status_code={html.status_code}')

    def get_html(self, params=None):
        try:
            r = requests.get(self.url, headers=self.HEADERS, params=params)
            return r 
        except:
            self.error.emit(f'Error: Что-то пошло не так.')
            return False

    def get_pages_count(self, html):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        pagination = soup.select('div.pages-list a')
        if pagination:
            return int(pagination[-1].get_text().replace('\n', ''))
        else:
            return 1

    def get_content(self, html):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        items = soup.find_all("li", class_="tile-container")
        
        phones = []
        for item in items:
            old_price = item.find('div', class_='old-price')
            price = item.find('span', class_='hidden', text='Цена:')
            if old_price:
                old_price = old_price.get_text().replace('₸', '')
            else:
                old_price = 'Скидки нет'
            if price:
                price = price.find_next('span').get_text().replace('₸', '')
            else:
                price = 'Нет в наличии'
            phones.append({
                'title': item.find('h3', class_='title').get_text(strip=TRUE).replace('\n', ''),
                'price': price,
                'old price' : old_price,
            })    
        return phones        
            
        

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    HEADERS = {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36',
        'accept' : '*/*'
    }
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()   
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.btn)
        
# !!! уберите две строки ниже и набирайте что вам надо
        self.lineEdit.setText('https://www.sulpak.kz/f/smartfoniy')
        self.lineEdit_2.setText('grgr.csv')

    def btn(self):
        if not self.lineEdit.text() or not self.lineEdit_2.text():
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Заполните поля ввлда.')
            return
        
        self.url = self.lineEdit.text()
        self.file = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        print(f'{self.url} -- {self.file}') #
        
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(False)
        
        self.thread = Thread(self.url, self.file, self.HEADERS)
        self.thread.stepChanged.connect(self.onStepChanged)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.save_file)
        self.thread.error.connect(self.error)
        
        self.thread.start()  

    def error(self, error):
        self.widget.append(error) 
        msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Error', error)
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(True)
        
    def onStepChanged(self, page, pages_count):
        self.widget.append(f'Парсинг страницы {page} из {pages_count}...')    

    def save_file(self, items):
        with open(self.file, 'w', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
            writer.writerow(['Модель', 'Цена', 'Цена без скидки'])
            for item in items:
                writer.writerow([item['title'], item['price'], item['old price']])
                
#        print(f'Получено {len(items)} товаров')
        self.widget.append(f'Получено {len(items)} товаров')
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(True)
        os.startfile(self.file)            
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы сделали принципе всё приложение за меня :3
Ща буду сидеть разбирать, что к чему)

Comment: @ДанилРумянцев пожалуйста.